# Enum conversion doesn't fallback to rest-messages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.8, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS. In my application exposing REST endpoints I enabled:

```
spring.data.rest.enable-enum-translation=true
```

In this way when I ask for an enum it is translated acconding to my locale.

Some more configuration stuff:

```
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        return new SmartLocaleResolver();
    }

    public class SmartLocaleResolver extends CookieLocaleResolver {
        @Override
        public Locale resolveLocale(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String acceptLanguage = request.getHeader("Accept-Language");
            if (acceptLanguage == null || acceptLanguage.trim().isEmpty()) {
                return super.determineDefaultLocale(request);
            }
            return request.getLocale();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("classpath:/i18n/messages");
        // messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        // set to true only for debugging
        messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(false);
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds((int) TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(1));
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSourceAccessor messageSourceAccessor() {
        return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource());
    }
```

As you can see I set also message source in order to translate also exceptions coming from the server.

My server locale is it-IT and I've `rest-messages.properties` (US translation) and `rest-messages_it.properties` (IT translation). My goal is to use `rest-messages.properties` when the language is not recognized and `rest-messages_it.properties` when the language is IT.

Right now it doesn't work. Spring Data REST read `rest-messages_it.properties` when there isn't a corrispondent file for the language selected.

I solved this problem with messages.properties using `messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);`. Is there a way to do the same thing for `rest-messages` files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you subclass the `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`, override and copy its method `resourceDescriptionMessageSourceAccessor`, but set **fallbackToSystemLocale** to `false` for `messageSource`?

```
@Override
@Bean
public MessageSourceAccessor resourceDescriptionMessageSourceAccessor() {

    try {

        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("rest-default-messages.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:rest-messages");
        messageSource.setCommonMessages(propertiesFactoryBean.getObject());
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

        // Adding this line:
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);

        return new MessageSourceAccessor(messageSource);

    } catch (Exception o_O) {
        throw new BeanCreationException("resourceDescriptionMessageSourceAccessor", "", o_O);
    }
}
```

---

And what if you create the `rest-default-messages.properties` file with values for the default locale?..

---

**Update from the question author**

To preserve spring.data.rest.* properties it's necessary to create a `RepositoryRestConfiguration` Bean as described in this [post](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392#issuecomment-70981467):

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.data.rest")
@Override
public RepositoryRestConfiguration config() {
    return super.config();
}
```

Comment: Great idea. I suggest as described here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392 to override also config() in order to preserve spring.data.rest.* properties. Did that, it worked perfectly. I just need to understand why java.time.Instant are not converted into ISO8601 dates as it happens instead without this configuration. Thanks

Comment: @drenda what do you think about Andy Wilkinson [comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392#issuecomment-355508251)? I did not understand it..

Comment: I had hard time to understand that as well. I took a look at RepositoryRestConfigurer but it's an interface and I should implements all methods. Furthemore I don't see any comment inside RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.

Comment: @drenda I think I guess now - he just confirmed what we should create a Bean as shown in the [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2392#issuecomment-70981467) ))

Comment: Yes I already did that in order to preserve spring.data.rest.* Maybe I explained it badly in my previous comment but the isn't enough space to write a well marked code. So that for sure, I would suggest you to add that in your reply. As last not, as I wrote, also with that bean java.time.Instant is not converted into ISO8601. I'll post a comment if I figure out how to solve and the reason why without this specific configuration it works.